# Attaching debugger to python script running on apache

Tags: python, apache, apache2, remote-debugging

I'm very new to this and am not sure if this is feasible.

All the requests for a specific file format to apache are redirected to a python script. Based on certain conditions, this script generates the output and returns that to the client.

I am using Eclipse + Pydev as my IDE. Once I make changes to the script, I upload it to the server using ftp. Is there a way, I can attach a debugger, so that whenever the script is run on the server, the debugger gets activated and I can put breakpoints and what not to debug it from there ?

I'd really appreciate any help, since debugging is a nightmare right now!

Comment: How are you using python with apache?  Using mod_python?  mod_wsgi?  fastcgi?

Comment: I use a scriptaliasmatch to redirect all the traffic for m3u8 requests to python script. And, I think it uses built-in cgi, since I didn't put in anything extra.

Answer (score 1):

What about [remote debugging](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) in PyDev
It is not *exactly* what you requested; you were talking about **attaching** to a process, while with remote debugging, you have the process connecting to your debugging server.
That said, I have been using this feature a lot to debug scripts running in apache / mod_python, and it was very effective.